# PHP export as XML error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: php, xml

When I see page source code in browser the field 'id' is missing
Code is below  and the result from page source in browser

```
// Start XML file, create parent node
$doc = domxml_new_doc("1.0");
$node = $doc->create_element("markers");
$parnode = $doc->append_child($node);



// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // Add to XML document node
  $node = $doc->create_element("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->append_child($node);

  $newnode->set_attribute("id", $row['id']);
  $newnode->set_attribute("name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->set_attribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->set_attribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->set_attribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->set_attribute("type", $row['type']);
}

$xmlfile = $doc->dump_mem();
echo $xmlfile;

?>
```

below is output from page source view from Chrome

```
<markers><marker name="Love.Fish" lat="-33.861034" lng="151.171936" /><marker name="Young Henrys" lat="-33.898113" lng="151.174469" /><marker name="Hunter Gatherer" lat="-33.840282" lng="151.207474" /><marker name="The Potting Shed" lat="-33.910751" lng="151.194168" /><marker name="Nomad" lat="-33.879917" lng="151.210449" /><marker name="Three Blue Ducks" lat="-33.906357" lng="151.263763" /></markers>
```

Some sample data

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/piC2L.png]

Comment: Please show a few rows of your *markers* table. Is there empty *id*?

Comment: intable marker have id column it is 1 2  3  thank you  i EDITED QUESTION ADD IMAGE THAT I CAPTURE SCREEN IMAGE OF TABLE MARKERS THANK YOU

Comment: That looks like PHP 4 DOM. You're really using that somewhere?

Comment: Seems not only the id attribute is missing, but address and type as well …? Have you first of all verified that the corresponding values in $row are actually set? If you are actually setting those attributes to “empty” or false, the might simply be left out when the whole thing is written out as XML ...

Comment: First, use a different MySQL API like *mysqli_* or PDO as *mysql_* is [deprecated in PHP 5.5 and entirely removed in PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Second, remove the *@* symbol as this suppresses any error. Third, try echoing out the *$row* values and see output.

Comment: I changed to use mysqli and it work  Thank you for all of you

Answer (score 1):

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "caico", "posxxxxt8", "ca888888co");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}



// Set the active MySQL database



// Select all the rows in the markers table
header("Content-type: text/xml");
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Add to XML document node
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("id",$row['id']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}
```

Comment: after change to mysqli  it is work thank for all help